# GCS Connector on EMR failing with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-storage, amazon-emr, distcp, s3distcp

I have created an emr cluster with the instructions on how to create a connection from gcs provided [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/copy-large-datasets-from-google-cloud-storage-to-amazon-s3-using-amazon-emr/) and keep running the hadoop distcp command.

It keeps failing with the following error:

```
2023-07-25 12:00:40,113 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1690268608656_0012_m_000002_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2637)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:809)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2635)
    ... 17 more

2023-07-25 12:00:47,139 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2023-07-25 12:00:49,149 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1690268608656_0012 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1690268608656_0012_m_000001
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0

2023-07-25 12:00:49,216 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 12
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=11
        Killed map tasks=20
        Launched map tasks=12
        Other local map tasks=12
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=5936160
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=61835
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=61835
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=189957120
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
2023-07-25 12:00:49,218 ERROR tools.DistCp: Exception encountered 
java.io.IOException: DistCp failure: Job job_1690268608656_0012 has failed: Task failed task_1690268608656_0012_m_000001
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0

    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.waitForJobCompletion(DistCp.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.execute(DistCp.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:441)
2023-07-25 12:00:49,225 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping s3a-file-system metrics system...
2023-07-25 12:00:49,226 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system stopped.
2023-07-25 12:00:49,226 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system shutdown complete.
```

Please comment if you need anymore information around this.

I downloaded the latest gcs-connector jar and the gcs service account json file.
Then did the following steps for manual setup:

1. Update the core-site.xml with the following dependencies:
   1.

```
 <property>
    <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl</name>
    <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS</value>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>fs.gs.impl</name>
    <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem</value>
    <description>The FileSystem for gs: (GCS) uris.</description>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile</name>
    <value>/tmp/service_account.json</value>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>fs.gs.status.parallel.enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

2. updated the hadoop_classpath with the gcs_connector location
3. added the gcs_connector jar location in mapred-site.xml under the property mapreduce.application.classpath
4. added the following properties for spark :

```
# The AbstractFileSystem for 'gs:' URIs
spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS

# Optional. Google Cloud Project ID with access to GCS buckets.
# Required only for list buckets and create bucket operations.
spark.hadoop.fs.gs.project.id=

# Whether to use a service account for GCS authorization. Setting this
# property to `false` will disable use of service accounts for authentication.
spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable=true

# The JSON keyfile of the service account used for GCS
# access when google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable is true.
spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=/path/to/keyfile
```

Also I made the gcs-connector jar to be executable and have been trying with both normal jars which are found on the [google docs site](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage#non-clusters) and have tried the latest shaded jar as well.

Also if I run the hadoop fs -ls gs://my_bucket it runs file and similarly hadoop fs -cp works fine. It only fails during map reduce

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the `gcs connector` and the `gcs_service_account.json` were only setup in the namenode and not the workers.
Had the setup everything in the workers as well.
Lesson to be learnt: always use a bootstrap script when setting up `emr` if there are extra dependencies to be used.